# Semaphore accessed by few processes concurently

Tags: semaphore

Is it ok if few/couple of processes access semaphore concurently or semaphore should be accesed mutualy exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the purpose of semaphore - to be safely accessible from several threads. Actually, how would you implement mutual exclusion? Having a semaphore with max value 1 is the easiest way. Semaphores are conceptually the very basic synchronization mechanism and they are meant to be used concurrently.

Behind the scenes the internal counter in the semaphore must be synchronized, but that should be addressed by e.g. the operating system. Accessing semaphore is inherently thread-safe.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Java guy ;-). Are you creating a semaphore using some OS routine and sharing it between several processes? If so, my answer still applies.

Comment: It doesn't apply, because if two independent processes access a semaphore concurrently, then they both can (not being aware of the other one) change the counter of the semaphore and by doing so put in inconsistent state.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I think you answered yourself; P and V routines have to be accessed mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Metz yes, I've just copped on ;)

Comment: A'm little confused: the definition of a semaphore is that it is a protected integral counter that can be accessed only with atomic P and V operations. If either P or V aren't atomic, we are dealing with int variable rather than a semaphore... How would you implement mutual exclusion? I guess every mutex uses the same atomic operations as semaphore, or maybe uses the semaphore itself.

Comment: @Tomek, please don't get me wrong for I don't have bad intentions, the only thing I would like to say to you is that: You are confused because java abstracts for you everything and you missing many very interesting things from programming world.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: no problem, I am aware of my limited mindset nowadays. My point was that according to what I've heard during my studies (and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))) semaphores can be accessed concurrently as the primitive P and V operations are atomic by definition. So there is no need to use mutex with semaphores created using `semget()`/`CreateSemaphore()`. Of course if you implement semaphore yourself on top of integer variable, accessing it must be protected. Thank you for your comment though :-).